# Evento disparado duas vezes no click Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript-eventos, click

Estou a tempo tendo problemas nos eventos do jQuery. Já utilizei de todas as práticas recomendadas para barrar o duplo evento de *click*. Segue exemplos:

```
.off()
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
unbid('click');
```

Sempre quando tem um click eu efetuo essa função

```
function LoadingTela(botao,tipo) {
     if (tipo == true) {
       $(botao).prop("disabled", true); 
       $('.mask-loading').show(); 
     }else { 
       $(botao).prop("disabled", false); 
       $('.mask-loading').hide(); 
     } 
 }
```

Alguém chegou a alguma solução ou novo controle de evento?

Comment: não entendi... você trabalhar com o evento de duplo click ou quer desabilitar o bind após o usuário clicar uma vez?

Comment: Como você está tratando o evento do click (o que chama a função)?

Comment: Não é só fazer `$('#botao').off('click').on('click', clickHandler);`? Na hora de registrar `clickHandler()`?

Comment: Sempre quando o usuario clica em um botão uma vez o evento e disparado duas vezes, ontem cancelei quase 1000 nf por conta disso :(

Comment: Estou fazendo asssim `$('#div').off().on('click','#botao'); `

Comment: O que é o `#botao` em `.on('click', '#botao')`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura para ser mais exato meu codigo esta assim `$('#divEmitirCTE').off().on('click', '#btnEmitirCTE' ,function (event) {   
        //aqui faco as verificações e chamo o metodo ajax Algo();                                                                                                                                                                              
      });`

Comment: Você tá removendo os eventos em `#divEmitirCTE` e, depois, pondo em `#btnEmitirCTE`! Por que não faz `$('#btnEmitirCTE').off('click').on('click', function (event) { ... });`?

Comment: se em um click o "evento" dispara duas vezes você deve estar fazendo o bind mais de uma vez

Comment: @MarceloUchimura o `off()` é executado antes do `on()` ?

Comment: @Guilhermezio, sim, na ordem que aparecem, na chamada

Comment: @MarceloUchimura como então ele retira o o evento adicionado no `on()`

Comment: @Guilhermezio, o `off(type)` retira (desfaz o _binding_) qualquer evento do tipo `type`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: `bind` e `unbind` ou `on` e `off` é complicar desnecessáriamente. Melhor seria fazer o `on` com base num elemento acima utilizando o alvo como seletor, assim: `$(document).on('click','#botao', function(){...});`. Dessa forma não tem problemas com registar multiplas vezes o evento de click